# Access Session version number in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

I know that once a session is accessed a session id is assigned by rails. I heard that if a session is modified, rails has a version stamp on the session. I am not able to find the exact reference to that, moreover, I was looking for a way to access the version number for the session? 
I know I am being vague here, but any help by pointing me to the right direction would be greatly appreciated.
I know it is possible to access the session id but I am more specifically looking to access the version number for the given session id, to track the number of times it has been altered.

Comment: Where did you hear about versioning of session data? Session data is disposable, changes all the time. You could add your own versioning if you store the session data but I have never heard of Rails versioning session data.

Answer (score 0):

> I know that once a session is accessed a session id is assigned by
>   rails. I heard that if a session is modified, rails has a version
>   stamp on the session.

This statement can be easily verified to be false by reading the source code of [`ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/fc5dd0b85189811062c85520fd70de8389b55aeb/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/cookie_store.rb#L1).

```
# frozen_string_literal: true
require "active_support/core_ext/hash/keys"
require "action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store"
require "rack/session/cookie"

module ActionDispatch
  module Session
    # ... comments truncated for readibility
    class CookieStore < AbstractStore
      def initialize(app, options = {})
        super(app, options.merge!(cookie_only: true))
      end

      def delete_session(req, session_id, options)
        new_sid = generate_sid unless options[:drop]
        # Reset hash and Assign the new session id
        req.set_header("action_dispatch.request.unsigned_session_cookie", new_sid ? { "session_id" => new_sid } : {})
        new_sid
      end

      def load_session(req)
        stale_session_check! do
          data = unpacked_cookie_data(req)
          data = persistent_session_id!(data)
          [data["session_id"], data]
        end
      end

      private

        def extract_session_id(req)
          stale_session_check! do
            unpacked_cookie_data(req)["session_id"]
          end
        end

        def unpacked_cookie_data(req)
          req.fetch_header("action_dispatch.request.unsigned_session_cookie") do |k|
            v = stale_session_check! do
              if data = get_cookie(req)
                data.stringify_keys!
              end
              data || {}
            end
            req.set_header k, v
          end
        end

        def persistent_session_id!(data, sid = nil)
          data ||= {}
          data["session_id"] ||= sid || generate_sid
          data
        end

        def write_session(req, sid, session_data, options)
          session_data["session_id"] = sid
          session_data
        end

        def set_cookie(request, session_id, cookie)
          cookie_jar(request)[@key] = cookie
        end

        def get_cookie(req)
          cookie_jar(req)[@key]
        end

        def cookie_jar(request)
          request.cookie_jar.signed_or_encrypted
        end
    end
  end
end
```

As you can see `persistent_session_id!` overwrites the existing session id cookie. It does not keep track of previous sid's. For the other stores such as sessions, memcached (dalli) and ActiveRecord  the don't appear to obviously delete the sid but there is no sort of "versioning" api in the way you have imagined.

If you wanted to have this functionality you would have swap ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore (or whatever store you are using) in the middleware stack with your own sessions middleware.

There probably is a an easier solution to whatever you're doing though if its common stuff like storing the number of user logins (store it in the db) or page views (use google analytics or the db) or what have you. Also if whatever you are doing needs to versioned - should it really be in the session in the first place?

Comment: Ahh, I was under the wrong impression then, thanks for correcting me and providing with an alternate solution. So by versioning, I just want to keep a track of if session has been modified. I had read in other blogs regarding replacing the middleware stack as you suggested, but those blogs were like 10 years old, so, I was expecting Rails to have changed( have this added).

Comment: Why would it be added? It would not be worth the added complexity.